# Can't get a return value from a foreach loop inside a method

Tags: c#, oop

I have a method in C# that finds a node with name `node_name` in node list `arg`, and returns the value of found node (assuming there's only one node with such name). If no such nodes are found, it should return an empty string.

```
public string get_nodes_value(XmlNodeList arg, string node_name)
{
    foreach (XmlNode arg_node in arg)
    {
        if (!arg_node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            if (String.Compare(arg_node.ParentNode.Name, node_name) == 0)
            {
                return arg_node.Value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            get_nodes_value(arg_node.ChildNodes, node_name);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The code above always returns an empty string. What did I miss here?

Comment: Maybe you need a case-insensitive search? Try using the compare function with ignorecase enum.

Comment: You might want to check out Linq-to-SQL.  You could do this as one Linq query.  After I switched to it I want to cry whenever I see someone using the old Object Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're ignoring the return value of the recursive call in the `else` block. Did you mean to return from there in some cases? My guess is you want something like this (fixing a few convention oddities at the same time):

```
public string GetNodeValue(XmlNodeList list, string name)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in list)
    {
        if (!node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.ParentNode.Name == name)
            {
                return arg_node.Value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Only return if we've found something within this node's child list
            string childValue = GetNodeValue(node.ChildNodes, name);
            if (childValue != "")
            {
                return childValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I think you have a bug when the node you search for is a leaf. You will always return an empty string.

Comment: @Petar: I'm assuming that the idea is to search for *text* nodes within *elements* of the given name. I'm just going on what the original code does though.

Comment: THanks for fast reply :)
That was what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever recursive invocation finds your node will return it, but unless it's the top-level that value just gets ignored. You probably meant to do something like:

```
    else
    {
        string value = get_nodes_value(arg_node.ChildNodes, node_name);
        if (value != "")
            return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find that out would be to step through the code while setting up "watches" on `arg_node.ParentNode.Name` and `node_name` and then you'll see which branches it'll end up in and you can find out why it didn't go where you thought it would go.